# Preserve multiple data (text, image, audio) loaded previously from a URL

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences, nfc

I'm currently in a situation where I don't know what I'm going to do.

Scenario:

There is this NFC-enabled phone and an NFC tag. The NFC tag contains the command to open a customized app that queries a php script that gets a list of food and all it's information in a json format respectively in the list. Included in the information are the text info, an audio info, and it's picture.

So if I have a listview of

- Spaghetti
- Carbonara
- Pizza

and when I click Spaghetti, it shows all information about spaghetti.

Since it's a php query, it is from an online database/server. Now, consider if a user closes the app, and lost internet connection. How can I make it when the user opens the app again, all the information are still there?

I thought of using SharedPreferences to keep the json file that I get from the query, but then the images/audio won't be loaded because those are uploaded in the server.

Is it possible?

Comment: you can cache all that stuff http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/HttpResponseCache.html

Comment: eduyayo, would that also include the audio/images which are only streamed online?

Comment: for streamming... nothing to do... but images inserted in html tags should work.

Comment: I have my image and audio uploaded in server. I have image in ImageView and audio in seekbar. Basically seekbar = audio url, imageview = image url. They're not embedded in the html of the url.

Comment: then u can use the cache just as stated in the example there in the API doc I´ve linked

Comment: eduyayo, thank you. I'll try that. I'll tell you what happens after I used it. Thank you again.

Comment: One More Note... for images u can use Picasso. It´ll cache out of the box http://square.github.io/picasso/